# Find all pairs in an unsorted array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, time-complexity, computer-science

I have come across a programming question in find I have to find all the pair in a given unsorted array such that

```
|i - j| <= K and |A[i] - A[j]| <= x
```

> For example:

```
 A = {5,4,8,3} and x = 3 and k = 2.
```

Answer: `(5,4), (5,8), (4,3)`

I have tried it many time but couldn't thought of any algorithm with time complexity less than `O(nk)`. I have also tried Balanced Binary tree but it is not helping me.

**Edit: Can we do something good if we have to find if such pair exits or not in an array (that means only one such pair).**

Comment: Considering the output size itself can be `O(nk)`, for worst case performance, you won't get better than `O(nk)`. Consider the following array for example: `[1,1,1,....,1]` with any `x`.

Comment: Thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/572670/amit. Can we do any better if I have to find if any such pair exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first N-1 entries, and sort them. That gives you min / max and the first few pairs. Then for each following entry in the list, does it match some, all, or none, based on min / max? if it matches none or all, you have your pairs straight off. If it matches some, do a binary search to find the cut-off points. Then delete the first entry and add the new one, using a balanced binary tree to hold the sorted list.

So you are O(N log k). In practice the overhead is going to be so high that it's unlikely the naive O(Nk) method can be beaten.

Comment: You run a  sliding window through the data. At each step, the new item is tested for pairs, then the oldest item removed, and the new item added to the window. In order to make large windows efficient, the window is kept sorted. A C++ set is designed for this task - it keeps a dynamically changing list always sorted.